# Ayuda con la siguiente consulta en sqlserver sobre pivot en la base de datos Northwind

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2017

Buenas este seria el ejercicio la base de datos que estoy utilizando es Northwind.
El ejercicio me pide lo siguiente:

Quiero saber por cada producto cuanto se a vendido cada mes-año,también por categoría lo vendido cada mes-año y agregar un total por categoría y producto lo que se vendió en todos esos años
Ejemplo

```
--NOMBRE PRODUCTO       Enero 1996      Febrero 1996      Marzo 1996      Abril 1996      Mayo 1996     ETC....         TOTAL DE TODOS LOS AÑOS Y MES
-- Categoria 1          1080            Total               Total           Total           Total       ETC...          TOTAL DE TODOS LOS AÑOS Y MES DE CATEGORIA PRODUCTO
--Producto1             50              1500                1110            111             1111        ETC..           TOTAL DE TODOS LOS AÑOS Y MES DEL PRODUCTO
--Producto2             510             1500                1110            111             1111        ETC..           TOTAL DE TODOS LOS AÑOS Y MES DEL PRODUCTO
--Producto3             520             1500                1110            111             1111        ETC..           TOTAL DE TODOS LOS AÑOS Y MES DEL PRODUCTO
-- Categoria 2          1120            Total               Total           Total           Total       ETC...          TOTAL DE TODOS LOS AÑOS Y MES DE CATEGORIA PRODUCTO
--Producto1             50              1500                1110            111             1111        ETC..           TOTAL DE TODOS LOS AÑOS Y MES DEL PRODUCTO
--Producto2             530             1500                1110            111             1111        ETC..           TOTAL DE TODOS LOS AÑOS Y MES DEL PRODUCTO
--Producto3             540             1500                1110            111             1111        ETC..           TOTAL DE TODOS LOS AÑOS Y MES DEL PRODUCTO
```

Este es mi avance hasta ahora conseguí hacer el pivot total por categoría con mes y año y al final un total de toda esa categoría en todos los meses-año

```
select *
from (select distinct C.CategoryName,
                      C.CategoryName C1,
                      datename(mm, o.OrderDate) + '-' + datename(yyyy, o.OrderDate) Fecha,
                      sum(((od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) * (1 - od.Discount)) + o.Freight)
                          over (partition by C.CategoryName,datename(mm, o.OrderDate) + '-' + datename(yyyy, o.OrderDate) 
                              ORDER BY C.CategoryName,datename(mm, o.OrderDate) + '-' + datename(yyyy, o.OrderDate)) TMA1,
                      sum(((od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) * (1 - od.Discount)) + o.Freight)
                          over ( partition by C.CategoryName 
                              order by C.CategoryName) TT1
      from Products as P
               join Categories C
                    on P.CategoryID = C.CategoryID
               join [Order Details] OD
                    on P.ProductID = OD.ProductID
               join Orders O
                    on OD.OrderID = O.OrderID) TDA2
pivot ( sum(TMA1) for Fecha in ([julio-1996],[agosto-1996],[septiembre-1996],[octubre-1996],[noviembre-1996],[diciembre-1996],[enero-1997],[febrero-1997],[marzo-1997],[abril-1997],[mayo-1997],[junio-1997],[julio-1997],[agosto-1997],[septiembre-1997],[octubre-1997],[noviembre-1997],[diciembre-1997],[enero-1998],[febrero-1998],[marzo-1998],[abril-1998],[mayo-1998])) PV1;
```

Igualmente lo consegui con los productos

```
select *
from (select distinct P.ProductName,
                      C.CategoryName,
                      datename(mm, o.OrderDate) + '-' + datename(yyyy, o.OrderDate) Fecha,
                      sum(((od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) * (1 - od.Discount)) + o.Freight)
                          over (partition by p.ProductName,datename(mm, o.OrderDate) + '-' + datename(yyyy, o.OrderDate) 
                              ORDER BY p.ProductName,datename(mm, o.OrderDate) + '-' + datename(yyyy, o.OrderDate)) TMA,
                      sum(((od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) * (1 - od.Discount)) + o.Freight)
                          over ( partition by ProductName 
                              order by ProductName) TT
      from Products as P
               join Categories C
                    on P.CategoryID = C.CategoryID
               join [Order Details] OD
                    on P.ProductID = OD.ProductID
               join Orders O
                    on OD.OrderID = O.OrderID) TDA1
pivot ( sum(TMA) for Fecha in ([julio-1996],[agosto-1996],[septiembre-1996],[octubre-1996],[noviembre-1996],[diciembre-1996],[enero-1997],[febrero-1997],[marzo-1997],[abril-1997],[mayo-1997],[junio-1997],[julio-1997],[agosto-1997],[septiembre-1997],[octubre-1997],[noviembre-1997],[diciembre-1997],[enero-1998],[febrero-1998],[marzo-1998],[abril-1998],[mayo-1998])) PV1;
```

Pero el problema no se como unirlos para que se muestre de la forma que me pide el ejercicio.
Nota : estoy utilizando sqlserver 2017
Nota : la base de datos es Northwind

De Antemano Muchas gracias.

Codigo para sacar los nombres de meses y años y guardarlo en una variable

```
declare
    @mes_anioM varchar(max);

select @mes_anioM = string_agg(MA, ',')
from (select quotename(Mes_Año) MA
      FROM (select distinct year(OrderDate)                Año,
                            format(OrderDate, 'MM')        Mes,
                            format(OrderDate, 'MMMM-yyyy') Mes_Año
            from Orders) TD1) TDA1A;
```

Comment: Tiene que ser usando pivot?

Comment: Buenas Si hay otra forma mas rapida y corta seria bueno no necesariamente con pivot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot es una instrucción bastante limitada. Desde antes de la introducción de esa instrucción, ya teníamos un método bastante eficiente y versatil que sigue sin ser mejorado por Pivot. Esa herramienta es el agregado condicional por medio del CASE (aunque podría ser IIF en versiones recientes). Como la forma de agregar los datos es mediante funciones de agregado y GROUP BY, tenemos acceso también a las opciones avanzadas de GROUP BY (ROLLUP, CUBE, GROUPING SETS).

Para este ejemplo, usando ROLLUP nos permite tener los totales sin problema.

```
SELECT ISNULL( p.ProductName, 'Total') AS Producto,
       ISNULL( c.CategoryName, 'Global') AS Categoria,
       SUM(( od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity ) * ( 1 - od.Discount ) + o.Freight),
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderDate >= '19960701' AND o.OrderDate < '19960801' THEN ( od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity ) * ( 1 - od.Discount ) + o.Freight ELSE 0 END) AS [julio-1996], 
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderDate >= '19960801' AND o.OrderDate < '19960901' THEN ( od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity ) * ( 1 - od.Discount ) + o.Freight ELSE 0 END) AS [agosto-1996], 
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderDate >= '19960901' AND o.OrderDate < '19961001' THEN ( od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity ) * ( 1 - od.Discount ) + o.Freight ELSE 0 END) AS [septiembre-1996],
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderDate >= '19961001' AND o.OrderDate < '19961101' THEN ( od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity ) * ( 1 - od.Discount ) + o.Freight ELSE 0 END) AS [octubre-1996], 
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderDate >= '19961101' AND o.OrderDate < '19961201' THEN ( od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity ) * ( 1 - od.Discount ) + o.Freight ELSE 0 END) AS [noviembre-1996], 
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderDate >= '19961201' AND o.OrderDate < '19970101' THEN ( od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity ) * ( 1 - od.Discount ) + o.Freight ELSE 0 END) AS [diciembre-1996], 
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderDate >= '19970101' AND o.OrderDate < '19970201' THEN ( od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity ) * ( 1 - od.Discount ) + o.Freight ELSE 0 END) AS [enero-1997], 
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderDate >= '19970201' AND o.OrderDate < '19970301' THEN ( od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity ) * ( 1 - od.Discount ) + o.Freight ELSE 0 END) AS [febrero-1997], 
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderDate >= '19970301' AND o.OrderDate < '19970401' THEN ( od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity ) * ( 1 - od.Discount ) + o.Freight ELSE 0 END) AS [marzo-1997], 
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderDate >= '19970401' AND o.OrderDate < '19970501' THEN ( od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity ) * ( 1 - od.Discount ) + o.Freight ELSE 0 END) AS [abril-1997], 
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderDate >= '19970501' AND o.OrderDate < '19970601' THEN ( od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity ) * ( 1 - od.Discount ) + o.Freight ELSE 0 END) AS [mayo-1997], 
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderDate >= '19970601' AND o.OrderDate < '19970701' THEN ( od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity ) * ( 1 - od.Discount ) + o.Freight ELSE 0 END) AS [junio-1997]
FROM   Products         AS P
JOIN   Categories       AS C  ON P.CategoryID = C.CategoryID
JOIN   [Order Details]  AS OD ON P.ProductID  = OD.ProductID
JOIN   Orders           AS O  ON OD.OrderID   = O.OrderID
GROUP BY c.CategoryName, p.ProductName WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY c.CategoryName, p.ProductName;
```

*Edición para agregar código dinámico.*

Aquí incluyo un ejemplo de como hacer el código dinámico. Utiliza varias técnicas avanzadas como el truncar fechas usando `DATEADD(DATEDIFF())`, una tabla de números, concatenación de cadenas usando `FOR XML`, así como el uso de formatos de código en `CONVERT()` y la función `QUOTENAME`. Además dejé la consulta parametrizada aunque en este caso no sea necesario, sólo para que sirva como ejemplo de como hacerlo correctamente y no se empiece a concatenar valores en la cadena.

```
DECLARE @FechaInicio datetime,
        @FechaFin    datetime;

SELECT @FechaInicio = MIN(OrderDate), 
       @FechaFin    = MAX(OrderDate)
FROM Orders;

DECLARE @Columnas nvarchar(max) = '',
        @SQL      nvarchar(max);

--Generamos el código de las columnas
WITH 
E(n) AS( -- 10 filas
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS( -- 10x10 = 100 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS( -- 100x100 = 10,000 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF( MM, @FechaInicio, @FechaFin) + 1 ) --limitamos el número de filas
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 AS n  --Generamos los números del 0 a N
    FROM E4
),
cteMeses(Mes) AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF( MM, 0, @FechaInicio) + n, 0) Mes --Le sumamos N meses a la fecha inicial y los convertimos al primer día del mes.
    FROM cteTally
)
SELECT @Columnas =( SELECT CHAR(9) + N',SUM(CASE WHEN o.OrderDate >= ' + QUOTENAME( CONVERT( nchar(8), Mes, 112), '''') --Convertimos el mes actual a formato YYYYMMDD y le ponemos comillas
                            + N' AND o.OrderDate < ' + QUOTENAME( CONVERT( nchar(8), DATEADD( MM, 1, Mes), 112), '''') --Convertimos el mes siguiente a formato YYYYMMDD y le ponemos comillas
                            + N' THEN ( od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity ) * ( 1 - od.Discount ) + o.Freight ELSE 0 END) AS ' 
                            + QUOTENAME( DATENAME(MM, Mes) + '-' + DATENAME(YY, Mes)) + NCHAR(10)--Tomamos el nombre del mes y año y los ponemos entre corchetes
                FROM cteMeses
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('./text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'); --Esta parte concatena todo en un XML y luego lo convierte en nvarchar(max)

--Juntamos las 3 partes de la consulta        
SELECT @SQL =  N'
    SELECT ISNULL( p.ProductName, ''Total'') AS Producto
           ,ISNULL( c.CategoryName, ''Global'') AS Categoria
           ,SUM(( od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity ) * ( 1 - od.Discount ) + o.Freight) TT
           ' + @Columnas + N'
    FROM   Products         AS P
    JOIN   Categories       AS C  ON P.CategoryID = C.CategoryID
    JOIN   [Order Details]  AS OD ON P.ProductID  = OD.ProductID
    JOIN   Orders           AS O  ON OD.OrderID   = O.OrderID
    WHERE o.OrderDate >= @FechaInicio
    AND   o.OrderDate <  @FechaFin
    GROUP BY c.CategoryName, p.ProductName WITH ROLLUP
    ORDER BY c.CategoryName, p.ProductName;';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, --Enviamos la consulta
                    N'@FechaInicio datetime, @FechaFin datetime', --Declaramos los parámetros
                    @FechaInicio, @FechaFin; --Enviamos los parámetros
```

Comment: Una pregunta mas como podria hacerlo mas dinamico si en el caso aumenta otro año mas tendria que estar agregando otra vez en la consulta seria bueno q fuera mas dinamico en la parte de los meses y años igual muchas gracias

Comment: Usando código dinámico se puede realizar algo que se actualice según un rango de fechas deseado. Sin embargo, creo que es necesario que permanezcas con código estático hasta que lo domines y puedas dar el siguiente paso.

Comment: Muchas gracias acabo de analizar mejor el código y lo veo mucho mas reducido y mas entendible, practicare mas con código estático muchas gracias enserio te pasaste. Si pudieras me gustaria ver el mismo codigo pero que sea dinamico para ver o tener almenos idea de como se hace de ese modo por mi parte estube investigando e hice algo para sacar todos los meses y años y guardarlo en una variable.

Comment: El codigo lo puse arriba en la pregunta

Comment: Muchas gracias esta genial esa consulta en serio te pasate cualquier cosa en la que pueda ayudarte aunque todavia soy novato pero si me es posible con gusto te ayudare en serio muchas gracias. Ahora toca entenderlo al 100%