# Consulta Dinamica / Pivot Sql server como hacerlo?

Tags: sql, pivot

Amigos foreros me han dejado realizar una consulta dinamica tipo pivot pero no me sale aver si podrian ayudarme?

Esto es lo que me genera el store procedure

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el resultado que quiero seria algo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En el pasado teníamos que hacer tipo subqueries, pero ahora existe Pivot en SQL checa el siguiente enlace viene un ejemplo muy simple y fácil  [Pivot](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15), también toma en cuenta que versión de SQL estas usando.

Comment: he realizado el pivot pero siempre lo agrega o agrupa con el max no me muestra todo los items.

Comment: ¿Te sirve [este ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/307774/ayuda-con-la-siguiente-consulta-en-sqlserver-sobre-pivot-en-la-base-de-datos-nor/308174#308174)?

Answer (score 1):

La solucion puede ser aplicando un `case` por cada valor del campo `Marca` asignarle `C_Equivalente` al nuevo campo definido con el nombre de la marca. Esta es otra opción sin utilizar `Pivot`

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT C_item 
,case when Marca='DON'then C_Equivalente end as DON
,case when Marca='BWD'then C_Equivalente end as BWD
,case when Marca='ECW'then C_Equivalente end as ECW

FROM #tablaTemporal 
 ORDER BY C_item
```